# How to hide the "type" element

Tags: javascript, ide, jsdoc

I find the "Type" part to be duplicating what has already been shown after the variable name. Is there any way to hide the "Type" part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about the [@param](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html) tag.

> The @param tag provides the name, type, and description of a function parameter.
> The @param tag requires you to specify the name of the parameter you are documenting. You can also include the parameter's type, enclosed in curly brackets, and a description of the parameter.

According to the documentation, the only mandatory part of this declaration is the name of the parameter. If you do not want to specify the type of the parameter, you can do so (BUT then you cannot benefit for example of IDE auto-completion, note that the description part is for humans-only).
If you have a given code, which uses JSDoc with both types and descriptions, it's the job of your chosen IDE what and what not to display. Though, I do not believe there's an IDE out there which will not display the type, if given, or it would be customizable in such way.

If you have something like

```
@param {string} name - string
```

then not the type definition is the extra, but the description is non-relevant/stupid.

Comment: thank you! seems like simply adding the type of a variable to the description itself is the way to go, because all data will be received from external sources and type check will not work in vanilla js.